# sorting of different color balls in minimum passes

Tags: algorithm

There are 10,000 balls and may be 500 different colors of ball

Example: There are:

4 - red balls

5900 - Blue balls

3700 - Green balls

396 - mintcream balls

Or there may be 10,000 red balls.

Or all balls are has same range, i.e. 500 red, 500 blue, etc.

We don’t know the range of any ball and number of color balls, but the minimum is 1 color and maximum is 500 different colors, and we have auxiliary array of size 500. how to arrange all same color ball together in minimum passes over balls and in minimum swap? is it possible to do in less than two passes ??

Comment: If you know there are max 500 colors, use a [bucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) or [counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) sort.

Comment: I presume you also asked [pretty much this exact same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186010/sort-many-balls-of-different-colors) a few minutes before this one (even though it's a different account). That question was downvoted and closed because it didn't show an attempt at solving the problem oneself. Similarly, this one doesn't show an attempt either. If you know how to do this in 2 passes (or more?), it would be wise to include that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need one pass (in pseudocode with OO syntax):

```
for (ball in balls) {
  array[array.getIndexByName(ball.color)].add(ball);
}
```

where getIndexByName returns the slot assigned to a certain color.
If no slot has been assigned to the color in question, a new slot is assigned.

Assuming a naive implementation of getIndexByName the complexity is O(number of balls * number of colors).

Comment: Could you clarify how `getIndexByName` would actually work? You haven't iterated over the balls yet so you don't know "number of colors" and you also don't know the number of balls per color. How can it assign a slot for a given color if it doesn't know the starting slot of all balls of that color?

Comment: @SimeonVisser The first available free slot can be assigned when a new color is encountered.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: that won't give the correct result. You don't know how many balls of that color there are (because you're doing only one pass) so how do you know how many spaces to leave free (after that) for the remaining balls of that color?

Comment: Each slot holds a number of balls (or **the** number of balls).

Answer (score 0):

First you go over all the balls and count per color the number of occurrences, you can do this using the auxiliary array you have.
Then you know how much space you must reserve per color. So when you go over all balls again you have a pointer to the location they should be going to in the output array since you know how many balls of every color you expect. Don't forget to update the counter of the color after you processed a ball.
By swapping the balls in the input array with the balls at the position they should go to you can get an algorithm of `O(n)` swaps.

An example:
The first part is simple, say you have 10 balls, 3 `red`, 4 `blue`, 2 `green` and 1 `yellow` ball.

The second part takes your input array: `red,blue,green,yellow`
For simplicity say we order them in the order: 
You start with the first ball. If it has color `blue` we have to swap it with the ball at location `4` in the array (since all balls before that have to be `red`. The new location we have to swap a `blue` ball to has to be updated in the auxilary array and should be `5` now. Then if the ball we swapped with is `green` we swap it with the ball at location `7`. Now if the ball is `red` after the swap we can continue with the next ball. You can of course skip the balls you have swapped before. It is important to note that you swap a ball at most two times using this technique and you swap them to a known location, hence you don't need an additional pass.

Answer (score 0):

you could do it in less than two passes, but it would be more complicated.
Here is how i would do it-
pass #1- determine number of balls for each color and number of colors
pass #2- for every 3 colors, (example 1, 4, 5, balls respectively=put a marker in 10th spot) and use the [dutch color flag problem here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem)